# Thread-pool don't use threads as expected?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, threadpool

*I'm trying to see what happens to the thread-pool when I extremely use it's threads :*

So I run this test :

```
void Main()
{ 
  int AvaliableWorker,AvaliableioCompletion,MaxWorker,MaxioCompletion;

  for (int i=0;i<1028;i++) Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{Thread.Sleep(5000);});

  Thread.Sleep(2000); // give the loop some time to run threads....

  ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out AvaliableWorker, out AvaliableioCompletion);
  Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", AvaliableWorker, AvaliableioCompletion);

  ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out MaxWorker, out MaxioCompletion); 
  Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", MaxWorker, MaxioCompletion); 

}
```

However , When I run it on my `.net4/32bit` environment (console)  , I get these results :

```
**1015** / 1000
1023 / 1000
```

Running again :

```
**1009** / 1000
1023 / 1000
```

The question is about the bold numbers :

**Question**

`Fw.4` sets a default max thread-pool worker threads creation up to `1023` (as you can see).

But looking at `GetAvailableThreads` :

[image]

If so , how come I still get big values like `1015 , 1009` **right as I make 1028 threads sleep** ?

I mean , `1023-1028 = negative number` : ( in other words : *"no more threads my friend , I will create them now on demand via 2 threads per second* —  <sub>but that's another unrelated topic</sub>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> right as I make 1028 threads sleep ?

You didn't. You queued about a 1000 Tasks, not (yet) Threads. Still waiting to run when you WriteLine() the results.

The actual number of pool threads at that moment: 1023 - 1015 = 8.

Make the Sleep() after the for loop a little longer (seconds) and you will see a lower number of available threads, ie a higher number of pool threads.

Comment: Henk I don't understand . after the main thread finished its 2 sec delay , there are `>1000` threads doing `sleep`. so how come i see `~1000` available threads?

Comment: No, there are 1000 tasks in a queue and only ~ 8 threads in the Pool.

Comment: Henk , I changed to 50 sec sleep , and 10 sec wait and it's still big number.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5SF6g.jpg ( isn't 10 sec enough for running 1024 threads ???)

Comment: `GetMaximumThreads` - `GetAvaliableThreads` is the amount of threads currently working in your application

Comment: @RoyiNamir - No, 10 seconds will add at most 2*10 threads to the pool.

Comment: by what formula did you use 2*10 ? what is the `2` ?

Comment: p.s. do you know what is the initial size  of the threadpool ?

Comment: `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` will probably tell you it's the same as `Environment.ProcessorCount`